# Trying to run mysql grant query from python using PEXPECT

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to run a mysql command through python pipe

```
cmd='CREATE DATABASE {0} ; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {1}.* TO "{2}"@"%" identified by password "{3}";'.format(requested_database_name,requested_database_name,'xyz',requested_password)
```

where the password is the hash generated from mysql. I always get

```
    ["ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% identified by password *ASSFS3FS2' at line 1"]
```

---

But when I see the output for the cmd I am trying to run

```
CREATE DATABASE db1 ; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO "xyz"@"%" identified by password "*ASSFS3FS2";
```

it looks good and runs well in the mysql prompt directly.

I use  `pipe = pexpect.spawn(cmd)`
to run these commands. I am not sure where I am going wrong in terms of formatting.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Never run multiple queries in a single command. There are high chances of SQL Injection, if you accept query parameters from users.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain a little more as to how having multiple queries increase the sql injection chances. Coz of more input variables from user? @thefourtheye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us the exact sequence of commands you use (surely you don't `pexpect.spawn` that specific MySQL command!) but it sure looks like you're passing `cmd` through a shell which, of course, is eating up those indispensable double-quote characters.

With no idea of what Python version you're using (since you chose not to tell us), it's hard to know what to suggest.  In 3.3 or later, `shlex.quote` is good.  If you're stuck on an earlier version no later than 2.7, `pipes.quote` might help.  But probably your best bet might be simply to replace each of those `"` with an escaped version:

```
cmd = cmd.replace('"', r'\"')
```

and try using the new version of `cmd` instead of your previous one -- this one should work independently of your Python version.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. That worked. I am using python 2.6 and you guessed it right I am using shell. Would keep this tip in mind for escaping a string and would keep in mind to mention my environment specific values in the future. Thanks.